# Twilio Flex Plugin how to add new tab with custom route

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I am using Twilio Flex plugin to customize flex ui in react js.
I want to add one custom link in a sidebar with a new custom component with new route URL like '/shops'.

After loading that component in that body i want to load custom shop.
Check the following screen for more details.
[image]

Thanks in advance for a help.

Comment: What have you tried with this so far? Have you managed to load your custom components into Flex yet? Have you followed [this tutorial to get started with Flex plugins](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/tutorials/building-flex-plugins)?

Answer (score 7):

I found this video by Twilio which helped.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMjKMoy1RPc

The key points are to add a new View to the View Collection and create a new SideLink which links to it.

```
import { FlexPlugin } from 'flex-plugin';
import { View, SideLink, Actions } from '@twilio/flex-ui';
import React from 'react';

export default class ShopPlugin extends FlexPlugin {
  constructor() {
    super('ShopPlugin');
  }

  init(flex, manager) {
    flex.ViewCollection.Content.add(
      <View name="shop-view" key="shop-view">
        <div>Your Shop View Goes Here</div>
      </View>
    )

    flex.SideNav.Content.add(
      <SideLink
        showLabel={true}
        icon="Thumbup"
        iconActive="ThumbupBold"
        isActive={activeView === 'shop-view'}
        onClick={() => {
          Actions.invokeAction('NavigateToView', {viewName: 'shop-view'});
        }
      >
        Shops
      </SideLink>
    )
  }
}
```